# Sorting Method to control escalations sequence

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have this table

seq    Name   Last_Name

1      Larry  Olson

2      John   Sullivan

3      Ana    Ferrer

I been trying to change Larry's sequence number to 2 for example so then John should turn 1, the same if I change Larry's sequence to 3, then John will be 1 and Ana 2. What I was trying to do is use Nested Tables, but I had a hard time trying to nest 2 tables. no look, if you know a easy method I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence number is from a sequence and you move those values around, be sure NOT to "create" new numbers or you will break constraints.

Use a temporary table, move the rows from tab1 - the real table, to tmptab a temporary table.  Update the data in tmptab.   Delete the thre rows from tab1, then insert them from tmptab.

Try this without nested tables:  `tab1` and `tmptab`  - WARNING practice on dummy tables first.

```
create table tmptab as
(select * from tab1 where seq <= 3);

update tmptab set seq =1 where name='Ana';
update tmptab set seq =2 where name='John';  -- this is just an example
commit;

delete from tab1 where seq<=3;

insert into tab1
values(seq, Name, Last_Name)
select seq, Name, Last_Name
from tmptab;

commit;

drop table tmptab;
```